# Install docker on debian 9

Tags: linux, debian

When trying to install docker on debian 9.8 I get the following error message when running "sudo apt update" or "sudo apt-get update":

E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 *Stretch* - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51] stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

I'm pretty new to Linux so I've no idea what I shall do.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tanktalus Well, I didn't know that.. but thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you installed your Debian from an ISO image or a CD-ROM drive.

Linux is the base system, and with every linux distribution (Ubuntu, Debian, Suse, etc) there's a package manager (apt in case of Debian). The package manager downloads packages from some source. Usually an online source. In your case, since you installed from some CD, it's looking for that CD to find more packages.

You can find the packages list in Debian in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (open it with root permissions to edit it). So go there, and find that CD source, and delete that line.

Then, depending on what you have left, you may have to add more. More information [can be found here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository).

After you're done, run `sudo apt-get update`, to refresh the package list.

Comment: So, I found the file in the explorer cause opening it with the command window didn't work for me. I found the lines:
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51]/ stretch contrib main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51]/ stretch contrib main


        --  Shall I delete all of them?

Comment: @temp Lines with "CDROM" should be deleted. Replace them with some online repository.

Comment: @temp One more reason `docker-ce` isn't available for  i386.